# How can I resume the previous activity with code?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using two activities first activity contain some edit texts and the second layout is displayed when the submit button is clicked.

So that the first activity is in pause state and when I press the back button from the second layout the first layout is resumed (That is the previous state is recovered).

Now I need the back button action in my own back button in the screen.

I tried with onFinish() in the button click but the previous state is not resumed.

I tried with startActivityForResult too.

Any other solution for this?
Please share your ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `finish()` method of your Activity. That will close your second Activity and resume your previous Activity.

Comment: that will not automatically restore the state of the first activity.

Comment: It will definitely resume the last Activity in the Activity stack. What do you mean by it will not automatically restore the state of the first activity (assuming that you haven't closed your first activity when you invoked the second one. In that case you'll have to fire a new Intent and restore its state manually).

Comment: @Aki i got the solution. you are right and the problem was in the functional flow.

Comment: the first activity will call onPause ... if you have some stage that you do not persist (e.g. position in a list view) in onPause and restore in onResume.. it will be lost when you get back.

Comment: Position in a listview **does** persist.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the first activity saves it's state in onPause somehow (e.g. using bundles, database, statics, application class, ...) and then that it sets up the state again from that persisted state in onResume.

Comment: ya the first activity does the saved instance. i am able to resume the first activity when press phone back button.

Comment: only if the first activity saves state properly in onPause like I said. If e.g. it has a current position on a listview and you do not save the position and restore it onResume it will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to save the state in

```
  @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think calling finish(); from arnab answer is the right thing to do. You should put:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

instead of finish(); but above startActivity();

Comment: True @IDontEvenKnow. Hope FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT will keep the second activity still alive. By the way this question was from me when I started android. What I wanted is, just to perform usual back on a button click. We can use "finish()" or "onBackPressed()" for my problem. Let me know if am wrong or not clear.

Answer (score 0):

`backButton.setOnClickListener(v -> { Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, PreviousActivity.class); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); startActivity(intent); });` worked for me `finish();` didn't resume the previous activity but started it.